# How to create draggable panel like modifier stack?

Tags: python

Is it possible to create a draggable panel like a modifier stack in `N-Panel`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create different panel classes inheriting from `bpy.types.Panel` class with the same `bl_category` and different `bl_label`s. Each class will represent individual panel in the stack. here is a simplified code:

```
from bpy.types import Panel
from bpy.utils import register_class, unregister_class


class MY_Panel(Panel):
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Dragable"
    bl_options = {"DEFAULT_CLOSED"}


class MY_PT_Panel1(MY_Panel):
    bl_label = "Panel 1"

    def draw(self, context):
        col = self.layout.column()
        col.label(text="Properties 1")


class MY_PT_Panel2(MY_Panel):
    bl_label = "Panel 2"

    def draw(self, context):
        col = self.layout.column()
        col.label(text="Properties 2")


class MY_PT_Panel3(MY_Panel):
    bl_label = "Panel 3"

    def draw(self, context):
        col = self.layout.column()
        col.label(text="Properties 3")


classes = [
    MY_PT_Panel1,
    MY_PT_Panel2,
    MY_PT_Panel3
]

def register():
    for cl in classes:
        register_class(cl)


def unregister():
    for cl in classes[::-1]:
        unregister_class(cl)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Not this, I mean a draggable panel inside a panel in `N-Panel`

Comment: Afaik, nested draggable panels are not implemented in Blender API. Anyway I can not provide a link to a reputable source. Hope you'll find a solution. The only thing I can state is that Properties is not a panel, it is a window, which has specific interface and behavior related to it. Properties' `Panel` classes' `bl_region_type` attribute is `"WINDOW"`, not `"UI"` like in N-Panel's classes. Their code has nothing specific which nests panels or makes them draggable, they just are. You can right-click on any parameter in Properties (except modifiers) and select `Edit Source` to see their code.